# Using Authorization header with app protected via cloud identity-aware-proxy

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have an application behind cloud-IAP(https://cloud.google.com/iap/) which has an admin authentication via API keys passed using `Authorization` header. In this setup when the request reaches the application, after it has been authenticated by IAP, the `Authorization` header is stripped.

Any ideas how I can make the application work?

Comment: Are you using signed headers? Take into accoun that your app must validate every request by checking the `x-goog-iap-jwt-assertion` HTTP request header.

Comment: The validation logic to ensure that IAP is in place and is not bypassed is not the problem, that logic exists. The problem is that my app which is sitting behind a GLB with IAP enabled need to consume an `Authorization` header which is sent by the client but this header is overwritten in the IAP authentication process.

Comment: Hello, did you find a way to do this ?